# How to fix cannot cast android.support.v7.preference.Preference to android.preference.RingtonePreference?

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, android-preferences

So i'm trying to implement this method to get the selected ringtone from a `RingtonePreference` but i'm getting this error at line

```
if (pref instanceof RingtonePreference)
```

I tried finding `android.support.v7,preference.RingtonePreference` but there was none in the existing packages.

should i import Gericop/Android-Support-Preference-V7-Fix from gitHub ?

```java
 private String getRingtonePreferenceValue() {
        if (pref instanceof RingtonePreference) {

            Log.i("***", "RingtonePreference " + pref.getKey());
            final RingtonePreference ringPref = (RingtonePreference) pref;
            ringPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new 
                      Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                                                  Object newValue) {
                    Log.i("***", "Changed " + newValue.toString());
                    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(
                            getContext(), Uri.parse((String) newValue));
                    ringPref.setSummary(ringtone.getTitle(getContext()));
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`android.preference.RingtonePreference`](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37057453#comment3) is **deprecated** and **there isn't** a `RingtonePreference` in the support libraries or androidx libraries.

[Google decided](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37057453#comment3) a few year ago to not move the class in support libraries.
In the same link there is a simple workaround, otherwise you have to create a custom `Preference`.